# How to open directly a directory(location) with JFileChooser?

Tags: java, directory, jfilechooser

Is there a possibility to open a preconfigured directory directly in the JFileChooser opendialog ?

I tried to set some directory with the follow code:

```
   File fn = new File("C://Users//me//Documents//Test");
   openFile = new JFileChooser();
   openFile.showOpenDialog(f);
   openFile.setCurrentDirectory(fn);
   fto = openFile.getSelectedFile();
   loadFile(openFile.getSelectedFile());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make JFileChooser open in the current directory the user is in?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844188/how-do-i-make-jfilechooser-open-in-the-current-directory-the-user-is-in)

Comment: Thanks, also useful, however I was looking for a solution like the below. Nonetheless I will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can go something like this:

```
String startPath = "C://Users//me//Documents//Test";
JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser(new File(startPath));
openFile.showOpenDialog(null);

File fileChoosen = openFile.getSelectedFile();
String fileName = openFile.getSelectedFile().getName();
String filePathAndName = openFile.getSelectedFile().getPath();

//Do what you want with the variables...
System.out.println(fileName);
System.out.println(filePathAndName);
```